# Can rotational electric field produce time varying magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

The Faraday-Maxwell law says that
$$ \nabla \times \vec{E} = - \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$$
Which is always explained as a time-varying magnetic field producing an electric field. But can we go the other way and say that a rotational electric field produces a time-varying magnetic field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equation simply says that two quantities have to be the same. It's not strictly accurate to use a word like "produces" which implies a logical directionality; the left hand side and right hand side are on equal footing, logically speaking.

In practice, often one side is "given" and the other side is "something to solve for." If you are solving for a vector field $\vec{V}$ as a function of space, then given its divergence and curl in terms of known functions, and assuming that the vector field dies off asymptotically fast enough, you can solve for $\vec{V}$ using the [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Statement_of_the_theorem). Applying this logic to Faraday's law, we can solve for an unknown electric field using the known "source terms", which include $\partial \vec{B}/\partial t$ (as well as the charge density). This leads to the language that $\partial \vec{B}/\partial t$ "producing" $\vec{E}$. Additionally, experimentally, it is possible to produce a time varying magnetic field; the fact that it is relatively easy to control the magnetic field experimentally in some situations also makes it natural to think of the equation in this direction (at least sometimes).

You are right, that if you thought of $\vec{E}$ as a known quantity as a function of time and space and wanted to solve for the unknown magnetic field, you could use Faraday's law to integrate $\nabla \times \vec{E}$ with respect to time and recover $\vec{B}$. This situation is not very common in practice, but there is nothing logically wrong with it.

In a more general situation, we don't know $\vec{E}$, $\vec{B}$, or the charges and currents as a function of time. If we know their value and time derivatives at some initial time, we can use Maxwell's equations (plus additional equations telling us how the charges and currents evolve) to solve for all of the fields, charges, and currents in terms of the initial conditions. Then, it's not really correct to say that either $\nabla \times \vec{E}$ produces $\vec{B}$, or that $\partial\vec{B}$ produces $\vec{E}$, but rather that the evolution of all the quantities is mixed together in a complicated way.

Comment: Thank you. This gave me a lot of clarity! If we consider a constant current (Known) flowing within a circular loop, it 'produces' a constant magnetic field along the axis. Since the current is in the loop doesn't that mean a rotational electric field is present and so that magnetic field should be time-varying, and not a constant field?

Comment: @GRANZER The law you are investigating is defined at a point in space and time, it does not apply to a circuit. If you use the integral form of the equation it is that $\oint \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l} = - \int d\Phi/dt$ and both the left and right hand sides are zero in the situation you describe (the sum of the EMF around a closed circuit with a steady current is zero).

Comment: If the wire is neutral and the current is constant in time, then $\vec{E}=0$ and $\vec{B}$ is constant so $\partial\vec{B}/\partial t=0$.

Comment: @ProfRob Just for clarity: If there is a constant current in a loop then there is an electric field but the EMF is zero even though the charges are going around and also the magnetic field is constant. But if the magnetic field is varying then also there is current in the loop but the EMF, in this case, is not zero on account of the induced EMF ?

Comment: The SUM of EMFs around a circuit is zero. Kirchoff's voltage law. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_circuit_laws @GRANZER

Comment: @GRANZER I should amend my comment. If the wire is neutral and the current is constant in time, then $\vec{E}=0$ (or almost zero) almost everywhere, except in the circuit elements where there is a voltage drop. For example, there will be a non-zero electric field across a battery, or across a resistor. Where $\vec{E}\neq 0$, it is constant in time. Since the current is constant, $\vec{B}=0$ so $\partial \vec{B}\partial t=0$.

Comment: @ProfRob Thank you so much. This has been very helpful. If you please, I have a last question: If there is a constant current flowing in a loop it means that the magnetic field is constant and the sum of EMF  around the loop is zero. There is an electric field going around the loop but locally this electric field is irrotational. On the other hand, a changing magnetic field associated with a closed-circuit again 'produces' an electric field going around the loop, but this electric field is locally rotational?

Comment: @GRANZER we're back to where you started. If there is a changing magnetic field at a position then there is a curling electric field at that position. The two are inseparable.

Comment: Andrew @ProfRob Thank you both! This has been great. I come from a fluid Dynamics background, and now I have a better understanding of Conservative and Non-Conservative/Inducted electric fields by comparing them to the concept of vorticity and circulation! Basically Inducted field in a circuit is like flow with Vorticity and Circulation while the Conservative field is like Circulation without vorticity.